# Drupal "enter key" not working in text area

Tags: drupal, textarea

I'm finding in any text areas the "enter key" is not working and does not create a new paragraph when I use it. This is for text areas which have a text editor enabled. I have tried it with tinymce and CKeditor and they both do the same thing. The strange thing is, when I don't have any buttons enabled, it works fine.

Can anyone help?

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Shift+Enter? I have found that to work before.

Comment: Hi Rodney, thanks for your answer. Yes shift-enter does work. Still not sure why just the enter key doesn't work though...

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked your input filter? There should be an option in the backend regarding how it treats line breaks. Maybe this is your issue?

Comment: I don't think this is my issue. The enter key doesn't do anything whether I'm using the filtered input format or the full input format. When I save the changes it shows the paragraph breaks, but not when I'm in the editing mode.